# How to remove mousemove from events that stop idlemonitor?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I want to use a simple p:idleMonitor for some logic.
But in my case, i don't want to restart the idlemonitors counter for a mousemove (only for click etc.)

Is this possible with javascript or with something else? The idlemonitor does not have any attribute for that configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to a JS file that loads after PrimeFaces to MonkeyPatch your IdleMonitor to only stop on `keydown` and `click` events.

The key is this line `events: "keydown click" // define active events`

This is based on PrimeFaces 8.

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.IdleMonitor) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.IdleMonitor.prototype.init = function(cfg) {
        PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.prototype.init.call(this, cfg);

        var $this = this;

        $(document).on("idle.idleTimer" + this.cfg.id, function() {
                if ($this.cfg.onidle) {
                    $this.cfg.onidle.call($this);
                }

                $this.callBehavior('idle');
            })
            .on("active.idleTimer" + this.cfg.id, function() {
                if ($this.cfg.onactive) {
                    $this.cfg.onactive.call($this);
                }

                $this.callBehavior('active');
            });

        var opts = {
            idle: false, // indicates if the user is idle
            timeout: this.cfg.timeout, // the amount of time (ms) before the user is considered idle
            events: "keydown click" // define active events
        };

        $.idleTimer(opts, document, this.cfg.id);


        if (cfg.multiWindowSupport) {
            var globalLastActiveKey = $this.cfg.contextPath + '_idleMonitor_lastActive' + this.cfg.id;

            // always reset with current time on init
            localStorage.setItem(globalLastActiveKey, $(document).data('idleTimerObj' + this.cfg.id).lastActive);

            $this.timer = setInterval(function() {

                var idleTimerObj = $(document).data('idleTimerObj' + $this.cfg.id);

                var globalLastActive = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(globalLastActiveKey));
                var localLastActive = idleTimerObj.lastActive;

                // reset local state
                if (globalLastActive > localLastActive) {
                    // pause timer
                    $.idleTimer('pause', document, $this.cfg.id);

                    // overwrite real state
                    idleTimerObj.idle = false;
                    idleTimerObj.olddate = globalLastActive;
                    idleTimerObj.lastActive = globalLastActive;
                    idleTimerObj.remaining = $this.cfg.timeout;

                    // resume timer
                    $.idleTimer('resume', document, $this.cfg.id);
                }
                // update global state
                else if (localLastActive > globalLastActive) {
                    localStorage.setItem(globalLastActiveKey, localLastActive);
                }

            }, 2000);
        }
    }
};
```